# compare div id with string

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I compare the id  of div with a string inside jquery and reload only the div with the new html which is present in `$newcontent` if it satisfies the condition, but currently it does not update the div with new content unless I manually reload the page.

```
function _(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

function toggle(mydiv){       
    _("page1_id").style.display = "none";   
    _("page2_id").style.display = "none";   
    _("page3_id").style.display = "none";           
    _(mydiv).style.display ="block";
}

function update_div(mydiv) {
    toggle(mydiv);
    if (mydiv=="page2_id") {    
        var mycontent='<?php echo $newcontent; ?>';
        _(mydiv).innerHTML = "";    
        _(mydiv).innerhtml('mycontent');    
    }
    _(mydiv).load(window.location.href + mydiv );
}
```

I updated my `update_div()` code...now when I reload the page MANUALLY irrespective of the page `div` it by default loads the page2_id....how to I get it load either the the default `page1_id` or the div currently active

Comment: Sorry, but where's jQuery inside your code? `function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}` is not what jQuery does!

Comment: js is client side while php is server side, I am pretty sure you cannot echo stuff in php coming from js

Comment: `return $('#'+x);` can help instead of `return document.getElementById(x);` to use jQuery functions like `empty()` you need a jquery object, not a normal element

Comment: With the way you set this up `if (mydiv == "page2_id"){` since `mydiv` is your id. But `_(mydiv)` is not a jquery object

Answer (score 0):

```
_(mydiv).innerHTML = "";
if (mydiv == "page2_id") {
```

Comment: but `mydiv` is the id

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to echo a php variable with javascript, which is not possible without using something like [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or a [websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) connection. And even then you can't use php in your javascript code.

Comment: If the code is in a `php` file you can do `var myVariable = '<?php echo "mycontent"; ?>';` without any problems.

Comment: Yeah, but i was assuming that he is trying to add php statements on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

First: Create a single PHP-File (example.php) which "echoes" $newcontent:

```
   <?php
     echo $newcontent
   ?>
```

Now do this in JavaScript (AJAX = Asynchronous Javascript and (X)HTTP):

```
    if (mydiv.id =="page2_id") {
        $.ajax({url: "example.php", success: function(result){
            mydiv.innerHTML = result;
        }});
    }
```

Assuming mydiv is a HTML DOM Object